# Excel formula to ignore blank cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following formula in Excel to count errors when the data entered does not appear in a specific list.

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(MyList,TestData)=0))
```

However, It is counting blank cells as an error. How do I get it to ignore the blank cells?

Comment: Could you share what your data looks like, what you're getting, and what you expect from that formula? If it's a lot of data, mock up a smaller version that still produces the unexpected behavior and share that.

Comment: perhaps first apply a filter to the list that potentially contains blank cells.

Comment: You can substitute a value with ISBLANK, the ternary operator: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/using-if-to-check-if-a-cell-is-blank-dff4eda1-6187-4b83-b7f6-4c3c0a1e2188

Comment: Adding a blank cell to `MyList`?

Answer (score 0):

You can [ignore blank cells in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985062/ignore-blank-cells-in-excel-named-range) by using the `Index` and`Match` functions.

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(MyList,INDEX(TestData,(MATCH(99^99,TestData,1))))=0))`

This function should return a `1` *only* if a number appears in the `TestData` range that does not exist in the `Mylist` range. Blank cells are skipped in `TestData`.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean blank cells in the TestData, try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(MyList,TestData)=0)*(TestData<>""))
```